# undefined reference to 'Ingresar_Elementos "

Tags: c

El error es:

> " **undefined reference to 'Ingresar_Elementos** "

No entiendo que significa, y no me marca en donde esta el error.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void Ingresar_Elementos(int Arreglo1[], int tamano1);
void Mostrar_Elementos(int Arreglo2[],int tamano2);

int main(){
   const int tam = 5;
   int vArreglo[tam];
   Mostrar_Elementos(vArreglo,tam);
   return 0;
}
void Ingresar_Elemetos(int Arreglo1[], int tamano1){
int i;

for(i=0; i<tamano1; i++){
    scanf("%i",&Arreglo1);
 }
}
void Mostrar_Elementos(int Arreglo2[], int tamano2){
int i;

Ingresar_Elementos(Arreglo2,tamano2);

for(i=0; i<tamano2; i++){
    printf("%i ",Arreglo2[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No te indica la línea del error porque este se produce en el paso de enlazado.

El problema que tienes es que el nombre de la función lo tienes como Ingresar_Elemetos, pero en el prototipo y en la llamada lo tienes como Ingresar_Elementos. Te falta la letra 'n'.

Answer (score 1):

Fíjate que donde desarrollas `Ingresar_Elementos` pusiste `Ingresar_Elemetos`. Te falta una `n`.